# Found water leak behind the wall - do we need to be worried about mold?

Tags: plumbing, mold, water-damage

Our contractor had installed the shower bar and drilled through the PEX pipe. He repaired the leak, but now we're worried about water damage.

Image in link attached: https://imgur.com/a/0YVlt3U

Background:

- This bathroom was newly installed, so we had not use the shower outside of the times we tested if the water had worked. When the water was running to the tub spout below, there was no water coming up this PEX tube so there should have been no water leaking anywhere.
- I looked up a "drip calculator" and I estimate the water was coming out at ~60 drips per minute, which means that for the ~20 minutes total we might have tested this in total over the last 2 weeks, we only should have at max 1L of water (I estimate approx 500ml) that had leaked into the area behind the drywall.
- The pictures below show the hole that was cut in the closet behind the shower. We left this to air out for a week. We placed a dehumidifier in the room and it was sensing the humidity to be approx 50%. We thought it was running the whole time, but it seemed to have malfunctioned so all in all, I believe we only pulled approx 8L of water out of the air during the week.

Should we be worried about mold growing behind the drywall? The room temp was likely approx ~24-27C the whole time during the day, dropping to ~18-20C at night. The contractor came back to seal off the hole today, but my wife is concerned the drywall was not fully dried out since the dehumidifier wasn't working properly the whole time. We read articles afterwards which explain that you should be cutting the bottom of the drywall since the water would have been on the floor. We didn't do this, so we're just trying to see what our next steps should be. Or would this be fine to just leave as is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the leak was fixed, the area will dry up and the mold will die